# Credit Card Processing API

Tags: online-payment

Not sure if this is the right Stack Exchange subdomain to ask this question... but here goes.

**What I need:**

A credit card processing API where our customers can "load money" onto their prepaid account.

**What I've Looked At:**

- Stripe
- SquareUp
- Authorize.NET
- dotNetCharge

**Why those don't work for us:**

We have an online service charges a very small monthly fee. If our customer loads, say, $100 onto their prepaid account, then the credit card processing company charges us about $3. Our service is $1/mo, so the card processing fee itself will murder us. Any recommendations?